# How can I erase part of an image to show another image under it?

Tags: animation, masking

I do stop motion with Lego and when I want to make something fly, I make a video with the character supported by bricks and/or clay, then I remove all the pieces from the set and take a picture; then, using GIMP, I import the blank image of the set and paste a frame with the character supported by bricks on top of that image and erase the bricks which shows through to the blank set image creating the impression of flying. I have been trying, for a few weeks, to do this in Blender to speed up the process and have not been able to find a way. How could I this in Blender?

Comment: A picture of you current Blender work and GIMP work would clarify your situation and probably draw more attention.  You can use GIMP to compose many pics into one as you know.  You may be limited as to how many pics you can insert into your question.  Are your trying to speed of your current image work with Blender or replace your physical work with Blender?

Comment: The use of the Blender Compositor is previewed here ........    http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50771/rotoscoping-to-a-transparent-background/50776#50776

Comment: Here is a link to a video which explains the process in Photoshop but it is the exact same as in GIMP              https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pYK-VDbOpuc

Comment: I am trying to speed up the process of masking out the support bricks not the physical process.

Comment: There are many ways of using this in VSE is very simple try intro to masking in VSE

Answer (score 1):

There are two and a half options.

1) If your support bricks are in the EXACT same location in every single frame, you can create a mask in the compositor, and use the VSE to render out the result. The mask could be used to composite in something else, or just make the masked area transparent. It depends on what you need.

2) If your bricks are NOT in the same place, but are a different color from every other thing in you scene, you can use a chroma key to create a mask of everything that's a particular color.

3) This is the half-option. If your bricks are NOT in the same location, and they're NOT the right color for a chroma key... you might be out of luck. However, if you're SUPER lucky and the tracking is good, and you're SUPER good at video editing in Blender, you could make a mask that tracks the edges of the brick, and use that mask to make the bricks transparent, or white, or whatever you need.

Any one of these would make a HUGE answer. Detailing all three of them is far beyond the scope of this answer. BUT there are good resources out there.

Some good searches are

- blender alpha mask video
- blender chroma key
- blender camera tracking mask

Searches are often difficult when you don't know what TERMS to use. Other times, Google is just overly specific. These searches seem to give good results.

I hope that helps!