# Isolating an object in a video

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is it possible to isolate an object in a video, and save it on a green or transparent background in Blender VSE?

For example, if I wanted to isolate a person walking in a video without any of the backgorund (with the aim to superimpose on top of another video) could this be done?

Comment: You can do that with a technique called rotoscoping: you create a mask around the object you want to remove (or preserve), and use that mask to control how the original image combines with others.The best way to understand the process would be to do a search for **masks** and **rotoscoping**. There are plenty of "tutorials" online on the subject.

Comment: related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1167/best-practices-for-masking-image-layers-for-compositing/1379#1379 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56376/how-can-i-accomplish-the-iron-man-in-helmet-effect-around-the-head-with-out-a-bl and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50778/1853

Comment: also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63134/how-do-i-mask-out-certain-areas-of-a-photo/63140#63140 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5131/using-mask-as-a-garbage-matte-to-hide-an-object and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15449/how-to-mask-animated-objects-so-they-arent-visible-past-a-certain-area and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52106/how-can-i-erase-part-of-an-image-to-show-another-image-under-it/52118#52118 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65007/overlaying-an-image-to-cover-a-face-in-a-video/65017#65017

Comment: @cegaton Thank you very much. That's great. I'll check the links out as soon as I get the chance.