# How would I Rotoscope a clip in Blender VSE? Can i?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, edit-mode

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMBBUmgGxnU&vl=en

i know it was made in Adobe Premiere, but how can i achieve that wipe effect in blender VSE?

Edit: How can I rotoscope a clip of a person walking across the screen to reveal another clip under it in Blender VSE?

Comment: Don't make users watch a video to understand what you want. Please explain the effect you are after soo it is searchable and post some reference images of what you want to achieve.

Comment: alright, not very easy to explain, but ill try

Comment: If you choose edit something like this into your question and title - How can I rotoscope a clip of a person walking across the screen to reveal another clip under it in Blender VSE?

Comment: Similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50771/rotoscoping-to-a-transparent-background

Comment: The VSE is not the right tool, you can use the **Video clip editor**. You can track sections of the video and use those trackers to control masks. To properly learn how to do this watch the "**Match, Track Blend 2**" series of videos by Sebastian Koenig.