# Is it possible to overlay a main video with a cutout of another video?

Tags: video

I'm imagining a shot where a man is watching a phone call in the background, then as the man on the phone walks past the man in the background he disappears

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: To be honest this is my first time using blender or doing VFX in the first place. I'm really just trying to figuring out where to get started.

Comment: What you want to do is not hard, but it will require you to get comfortable with the tools. Basically what you need load the two layers of video in the compositor and use a mask to control a mix node. See if this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63134/how-do-i-mask-out-certain-areas-of-a-photo/63197#63197

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50778/1853 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23865/is-it-possible-to-take-a-mask-clip-and-connect-it-to-a-specific-point-on-a-mov/23902#23902 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/composite-a-3d-object-into-a-photograph

Comment: Thanks a ton, I'll look into it

Comment: To help you further please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on things you have tried and what resluts you are getting. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Will do, thanks for getting me started